# Text doesn't appear when outputting it on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been working on a notebook web app, my problem is that if I write a note and save it, when I press on its title to read it again it just shows me an empty screen. Here is the code for the app:

```js
const main = document.getElementById("main");
const add = document.getElementById("add"); //new note
const submit = document.getElementById("submit"); //submit the new note
const cancel = document.getElementById("cancel");
const screen = document.getElementById("screen");
const ul = document.getElementById("list");
const del = document.getElementById("delete"); 
const note = document.getElementById("note");
const back = document.getElementById("back");
const noteTitle = document.getElementById("note-title");
const inputTitle = document.getElementById("input-title");
const err1 = document.getElementById("err1");
const err2 = document.getElementById("err2");
const err3 = document.getElementById("err3");
const text = document.getElementById("text");

let flag1 = false;
let flag2 = false;
let flag3 = false;

let mynotes = {};
let i = 1;

add.addEventListener('click', function(){
    main.style.display = "block";
    submit.style.display = "inline";
    cancel.style.display = "inline";
    add.style.display = "none";
    screen.style.display = "none";
    del.style.display = "none";
    back.style.display = "none";
    inputTitle.style.display = "block"
});

submit.addEventListener('click', function(){
    title = noteTitle.value;
    newNote = note.value;
    
    if (title.length < 3){
        err1.style.display = "block";
        flag1 = true;
    } else {
        err1.style.display = "none";
        flag1 = false
    }

    if (newNote === ""){
        err2.style.display = "block";
        flag2 = true;
    } else {
        err2.style.display = "none";
        flag2 = false;
    }

    if (mynotes.hasOwnProperty(title)){
        err3.style.display = "block";
        flag3 = true;
    } else {
        err3.style.display = "none";
        flag3 = false;
    }

    if (!flag1 && !flag2 && !flag3) {
        newNote = newNote.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
        mynotes[title] = newNote;

        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.setAttribute('class','item');
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title));
        ul.appendChild(li);
        main.style.display = "none";
        screen.style.display = "block";
        submit.style.display = "none";
        cancel.style.display = "none";
        add.style.display = "inline";
        del.style.display = "none";
        back.style.display = "none";
        inputTitle.style.display = "none";
        note.value = "";
        noteTitle.value = "";
    } 
});



ul.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    node = event.target;
    item = event.target.textContent;
    text.innerHTML = mynotes[item];
    fullnote.style.display = "block";
    main.style.display = "none";
    submit.style.display = "none";
    add.style.display = "none";
    screen.style.display = "none";
    cancel.style.display = "none";
    del.style.display = "inline";
    back.style.display = "inline";
    inputTitle.style.display = "none";
});

del.addEventListener('click', function(){
    ul.removeChild(node);
    delete mynotes[item];
    main.style.display = "none";
    screen.style.display = "block";
    submit.style.display = "none";
    add.style.display = "inline";
    fullnote.style.display = "none";
    back.style.display = "none";
    del.style.display = "none";
    inputTitle.style.display = "none";
});

cancel.addEventListener('click', function(){
    note.value = "";
    main.style.display = "none";
    screen.style.display = "block";
    submit.style.display = "none";
    add.style.display = "inline";
    fullnote.style.display = "none";
    del.style.display = "none";
    back.style.display = "none";
    cancel.style.display = "none";
    inputTitle.style.display = "none";
});

back.addEventListener('click', function(){
    main.style.display = "none";
    screen.style.display = "block";
    submit.style.display = "none";
    add.style.display = "inline";
    fullnote.style.display = "none";
    back.style.display = "none";
    del.style.display = "none";
    inputTitle.style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
#container {
    background-color: rgb(253, 248, 177);
}

#header, #footer {
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

#footer {
  bottom: 0;
}

#screen, #input-title {
  margin-top: 2em;
} 

#title {
    color: white;
    padding-top: 7px; 
}

#cancel, #submit, #back {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#add {
    font-size: 20px; 
}

#delete, #cancel, #submit {
    display: none;
}

#input-title {
    display: none;
}

#main {
    display: none;
}


#note {
    resize: none;
}


#fullnote {
    display: none;
}

#back {
    display: none;
}

#err1 {
    color: red;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: none;
}

#err2 {
    color: red;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: none;
}

#err3 {
    color: red;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- link to css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>Notebook</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    
    <div class="container min-vh-100 d-flex flex-column" id="container">

      <!-- header -->
      <div class="row align-items-start bg-info container" id="header">
        <div class="col text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn" id="cancel">&#10007;</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn" id="back">&#8617;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">
          <h4 id="title">Notebook</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn" id="submit">&#10004;</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <br />

      <!-- Screen list show -->
        <div class="row" id="screen">
            <div class="col-12">
                <ul id="list">
                  
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Note show -->
      <div class="row" id="fullnote">
            <div class="col-12">
              <p id="text"> 
              </p>
            </div>
        </div>

      <!-- input for note title -->
      <div class="row" id="input-title">
        <div class="col">
            <input type="text" maxlength="20" class="form-control" placeholder="Note title" value="" id="note-title">
            <p id="err1">Title must be at least 3 characters</p>
            <p id="err3">There is a note with this title</p>
          </div>
      </div>

      <br />
      <!-- textarea for writing note -->
      <div class="row flex-grow-1">
        <div class="col" id="main">
            <textarea class="form-control textarea h-100" value="" placeholder="write note" id="note"></textarea>
            <p id="err2">Note can not be empty</p>
          </div>
      </div>

      <br />

      
      <!-- footer -->
      <div class="row align-items-end container" id="footer">
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-start" style="padding: 10px; padding-left: 25px;">
          <button id="add" class="btn btn-info rounded-circle"><h4 style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">&#x2b;</h4></button>
          <button id="delete" class="btn btn-info rounded-circle">&#128465;</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    
    </div>

    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Steps to recreate the issue:**
Try to add a note, save it, and press on it's title to read the note and you'll understand what I mean.

Comment: because it is hidden under the bar....Seems weird how you position it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in your `<p id="text">` tag. It was hidden behind the blue header. Just used a couple of `<br>` and it is visible now.

```js
const main = document.getElementById("main");
const add = document.getElementById("add"); //new note
const submit = document.getElementById("submit"); //submit the new note
const cancel = document.getElementById("cancel");
const screen = document.getElementById("screen");
const ul = document.getElementById("list");
const del = document.getElementById("delete"); 
const note = document.getElementById("note");
const back = document.getElementById("back");
const noteTitle = document.getElementById("note-title");
const inputTitle = document.getElementById("input-title");
const err1 = document.getElementById("err1");
const err2 = document.getElementById("err2");
const err3 = document.getElementById("err3");
const text = document.getElementById("text");

let flag1 = false;
let flag2 = false;
let flag3 = false;

let mynotes = {};
let i = 1;

add.addEventListener('click', function(){
    main.style.display = "block";
    submit.style.display = "inline";
    cancel.style.display = "inline";
    add.style.display = "none";
    screen.style.display = "none";
    del.style.display = "none";
    back.style.display = "none";
    inputTitle.style.display = "block"
});

submit.addEventListener('click', function(){
    title = noteTitle.value;
    newNote = note.value;
    
    if (title.length < 3){
        err1.style.display = "block";
        flag1 = true;
    } else {
        err1.style.display = "none";
        flag1 = false
    }

    if (newNote === ""){
        err2.style.display = "block";
        flag2 = true;
    } else {
        err2.style.display = "none";
        flag2 = false;
    }

    if (mynotes.hasOwnProperty(title)){
        err3.style.display = "block";
        flag3 = true;
    } else {
        err3.style.display = "none";
        flag3 = false;
    }

    if (!flag1 && !flag2 && !flag3) {
        newNote = newNote.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
        mynotes[title] = newNote;

        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.setAttribute('class','item');
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title));
        ul.appendChild(li);
        main.style.display = "none";
        screen.style.display = "block";
        submit.style.display = "none";
        cancel.style.display = "none";
        add.style.display = "inline";
        del.style.display = "none";
        back.style.display = "none";
        inputTitle.style.display = "none";
        note.value = "";
        noteTitle.value = "";
    } 
});



ul.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    node = event.target;
    item = event.target.textContent;
    console.log(mynotes[item])
    text.innerHTML = mynotes[item];
    fullnote.style.display = "block";
    main.style.display = "none";
    submit.style.display = "none";
    add.style.display = "none";
    screen.style.display = "none";
    cancel.style.display = "none";
    del.style.display = "inline";
    back.style.display = "inline";
    inputTitle.style.display = "none";
});

del.addEventListener('click', function(){
    ul.removeChild(node);
    delete mynotes[item];
    main.style.display = "none";
    screen.style.display = "block";
    submit.style.display = "none";
    add.style.display = "inline";
    fullnote.style.display = "none";
    back.style.display = "none";
    del.style.display = "none";
    inputTitle.style.display = "none";
});

cancel.addEventListener('click', function(){
    note.value = "";
    main.style.display = "none";
    screen.style.display = "block";
    submit.style.display = "none";
    add.style.display = "inline";
    fullnote.style.display = "none";
    del.style.display = "none";
    back.style.display = "none";
    cancel.style.display = "none";
    inputTitle.style.display = "none";
});

back.addEventListener('click', function(){
    main.style.display = "none";
    screen.style.display = "block";
    submit.style.display = "none";
    add.style.display = "inline";
    fullnote.style.display = "none";
    back.style.display = "none";
    del.style.display = "none";
    inputTitle.style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
#container {
    background-color: rgb(253, 248, 177);
}

#header, #footer {
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

#footer {
  bottom: 0;
}

#screen, #input-title {
  margin-top: 2em;
} 

#title {
    color: white;
    padding-top: 7px; 
}

#cancel, #submit, #back {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#add {
    font-size: 20px; 
}

#delete, #cancel, #submit {
    display: none;
}

#input-title {
    display: none;
}

#main {
    display: none;
}


#note {
    resize: none;
}


#fullnote {
    display: none;
}

#back {
    display: none;
}

#err1 {
    color: red;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: none;
}

#err2 {
    color: red;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: none;
}

#err3 {
    color: red;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- link to css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>Notebook</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    
    <div class="container min-vh-100 d-flex flex-column" id="container">

      <!-- header -->
      <div class="row align-items-start bg-info container" id="header">
        <div class="col text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn" id="cancel">&#10007;</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn" id="back">&#8617;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">
          <h4 id="title">Notebook</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn" id="submit">&#10004;</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <br />

      <!-- Screen list show -->
        <div class="row" id="screen">
            <div class="col-12">
                <ul id="list">
                  
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Note show -->
      <div class="row" id="fullnote">
            <div class="col-12">
            <br><br>
              <p id="text"> 
              </p>
            </div>
        </div>

      <!-- input for note title -->
      <div class="row" id="input-title">
        <div class="col">
            <input type="text" maxlength="20" class="form-control" placeholder="Note title" value="" id="note-title">
            <p id="err1">Title must be at least 3 characters</p>
            <p id="err3">There is a note with this title</p>
          </div>
      </div>

      <br />
      <!-- textarea for writing note -->
      <div class="row flex-grow-1">
        <div class="col" id="main">
            <textarea class="form-control textarea h-100" value="" placeholder="write note" id="note"></textarea>
            <p id="err2">Note can not be empty</p>
          </div>
      </div>

      <br />

      
      <!-- footer -->
      <div class="row align-items-end container" id="footer">
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-start" style="padding: 10px; padding-left: 25px;">
          <button id="add" class="btn btn-info rounded-circle"><h4 style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">&#x2b;</h4></button>
          <button id="delete" class="btn btn-info rounded-circle">&#128465;</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    
    </div>

    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the note text is under the header.
Add some margin to the note text section

```
#fullnote {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually working exactly as you expect. The problem isn't that the full text of the note isn't being displayed, it is that your `fullnote` element has not been pushed down (`margin-top`, most likely), placing it directly behind the `#header` div.

I would suggest strongly that you use the Chrome Developer Tools (or if you're on another platform, their dev tools). It will allow you to see if there are javascript errors, and also to poke around in the DOM structure itself. By doing this, I could see the `#fullnote`, and that it did, in fact, contain the text of the note as you'd wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The fullnote  element is actually hidden by green bar

Change CSS to

```
#fullnote {
    margin-top: 25px;
    display: none;
}
```